# Applications resized after wake/unlock on a HiDPI monitor

Tags: xorg, suspend, display-resolution

I have a laptop (Thinkpad t480) with a 1440p monitor. I'm running Disco (19.04) with Gnome Shell running under Xorg, for stability and compatibility.

The lock and boot splash screens detect my HiDPI monitor, and automatically use 200% scaling. I don't want to run my desktop at 720p, however, so I have scaling turned off once I've logged in.

The problem is that some applications -- most notably Terminal, Emacs, Thunderbird and Firefox -- wind up resized to fit a 720p desktop after I wake from suspend and unlock my laptop. (Chrome and Electron based applications are not affected.)

It feels like there's an order of operations issue, where application sizing is getting applied before my monitor switches scaling/resolution.

Has anybody else run into this? And does anyone have a workaround?

It feels like one solution would be to turn off scaling on the splash and lock screens, but I haven't discovered a way to do that. And I don't really know where to start in the chain of GUI things when it comes to filing bugs and submitting patches ...

Comment: Disco is version 19.04 but you say it's 19.10. Are you running 19.04?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Whoops. You are right. I have 19.10 on my brain, but I am still running 19.04 on my laptop. Edited the post to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, this laptop also exhibited the problem under Cosmic.

Comment: A quick follow-up. I still see this behavior after upgrading to 19.10. I haven't done a clean install at any point in this process, however.

Comment: There are lots of bugs reported upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10. You should keep checking via google search for new bugs that fit your description.